# Azure Functions publish to RabbitMQ using MassTransit

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am currently running an Azure Function that is using Masstransit to publish to an Azure Service Bus. For ease of debugging, I would like to be able to run the function locally and publish to a local RabbitMQ instance instead.

On the consumer side everything connects well and I can publish messages through the RabbitMQ Management UI. However on the Function, I keep seeing the following exception when trying to configure RabbitMQ:

> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: 'SetBusFactory' can be called only once.

This is my Function Startup.cs

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder
            .Services
            .AddScoped<MyService1>()
            .AddScoped<MyService2>()
            .AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(massTransitConfig =>
            {
                massTransitConfig.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                });
                massTransitConfig.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
            }, "AzureWebJobsServiceBus");
    }
```

I was checking the source code for the **AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions** method and it seems to automatically add a connection to an Azure Service Bus instance. Does this mean that there is currently no support for RabbitMQ for Azure Functions? Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Framework - .NET 6.0
Relevant Libraries - MassTransit 8.0.15, MassTransitRabbitMQ 8.0.15

Comment: According to the error message, it occurs because the `AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions` method already sets up a bus factory for Azure Service Bus, and you're attempting to configure a RabbitMQ transport using `UsingRabbitMq`
In order to publish to RabbitMQ locally, use the generic host builder or conditionally configure MassTransit based on the environment. Ensure your code works with Azure Service Bus when deployed and consider environment variables .

Answer (score 0):

- The error "MassTransit.ConfigurationException: 'SetBusFactory' can be called only once" occurs because `AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions` configures MassTransit with Azure Service Bus by default. Your attempt to use `UsingRabbitMq` conflicts with this existing configuration. Thanks to @Md Farid Uddin Kiron for the comment about the method.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                });
            });
            // ... other services
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

[image]

Another method is to integrate Service Bus with RabbitMQ and use RabbitMQ and MassTransit using the links below:

- How to integrate Service Bus with [RabbitMQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-integrate-with-rabbitmq)
- Getting Started with [MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/rabbitmq) and [RabbitMQ](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-masstransit-and-rabbitmq/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this case it would be purely to use MassTransit on my local environment for debugging purposes, since having a Service Bus for that is not an option on this case.

I was able to successfully connect to my local rabbitMQ instance using a Console Application, but the Azure Functions AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions seems to force using a Service Bus. I was wondering if there is any reason for this (incompatibility of Azure Functions with MassTransit RabbitMQ) or if there is an alternative way to do this